# How to print greyscale image with alpha using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, png

I' am writing a simple PNG parser that can decode PNG data and print raw pixels using matplotlib.
I have no problem printing RGB, RGBA and pure greyscale.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with PngParser() as png:
    if png.greyscale:
        plt.imshow(np.array(png.reconstructed_data).reshape((png.height, png.width)), cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
        plt.show()
    elif png.greyalhpa:
        ?
    else:
        # RGB, RGBA
        plt.imshow(np.array(png.reconstructed_data).reshape((png.height, png.width, png.bytesPerPixel)))
        plt.show()
```

Where `png.reconstructed_data` is a simple array of pixels.

Unfortunatelly, matplotlib don't explicitly supports this kind of image. Here is a quote from [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

> Supported array shapes are: 
> (M, N):  an image with
>   scalar data. The values are mapped to colors using normalization and a
>   colormap. See parameters norm, cmap, vmin, vmax. 
> (M, N, 3): an image
>   with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int). 
> (M, N, 4): an image with
>   RGBA values (0-1 float or 0-255 int), i.e. including transparency. The
>   first two dimensions (M, N) define the rows and columns of the image.

Our shape would be (M, N, 2) .

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: You could use **PIL/Pillow**, `from PIL import Image` then `Image.fromarray(YourNumpyArray).show()`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!
I think the best workaround is to use `np.tile` to duplicate your grayscale data into 3 channels, and then display it as an RGB image.

Comment: @beenjaminnn Don't know why but image after `np.tile` is being considered as green. What's more, pixels are shown as [255, 0, 255, 0] which should be purple I think.

Comment: My apologies, `np.dstack` is what you want. I posted an example

Comment: Just a side note -> @MarkSetchell solution is also working, but this question was about matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think turning the grayscale image into an RGB image is the best workaround. You do this by replicating the image in each channel. This will allow you to handle images with different alpha values for each pixel.

```
height = 10
width = 10

# example image
img = np.random.random(size=(height, width, 2))

# separate out image and alpha channel
grayscale = img[:, :, 0]
alpha = img[:, :, 1]

# repeat grayscale image for each channel 
rgb_img = np.dstack((grayscale, grayscale, grayscale, alpha))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax[0].imshow(grayscale, cmap='gray')
ax[1].imshow(alpha)
ax[2].imshow(rgb_img)
```

[image]